# Are there browsers that support CSS rotation but no canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas

I build something using Canvas and the Rafaël library, where I need a rotation of an element (path or image). You can drag the bottom right circle and the arm will extend appropriately.

http://wstaw.org/m/2013/02/13/Auswahl_001_1.png

It should work with older browser where Canvas is not supported, so CSS rotations came up. Does it make any sense to rebuild this Canvas thing using `position: absolute` `img` elements, jQuery and CSS rotations as a fall-back?

Comment: It's a good idea when creating a project like this to determine what each browser can and can't do. Start with a base project that is compatible across all the browsers then build up. It's the idea of [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). To help with identifying what browsers support what features, you may want to look into [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It uses feature detection and provides for a way of adding support with polyfills using `yepnope.js` to browsers that don't support a particular feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the support status here:

http://caniuse.com/#search=transform

http://caniuse.com/#search=canvas

Quickly, looks like *canvas* is more supported than *CSS3 transforms* needed for rotation. So I think your idea might not work.